# USB Keyboard not recognized during installation

Tags: keyboard

USB Keyboard not recognized during installation at language select screen.  Tab, space, enter don't work.  16.04 server, Acer, intel.  How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

I have heard ppl having luck unplugging the usb when the issue happens and plugging it into a different sub port